# How to prevent visual glitchs on push animation when UINavigationBar height changes?

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

I have a visual glitch specific to iOS 11.
I have a navigation controller with a search bar and on item click I push another view Controller. Before iOS 11, the animation is clean because the navigation bar height does not change between the source view controller and the destination view controller.
With iOS 11, the Search Bar is taller, so navigation bar height changes during push animations and I have visual glitch.

[image]

I tried to force navigation bar height without success. Any idea how to handle this?

Comment: I think this approach may be not intended by Apple. The "better" (well, in Apple's point of view) is that you make this search bar in the view itself, or as a header view of the collection view. Regarding your approach, I think there is a lot of handling and rework.